# date subtraction - day 31th are missing. sql 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a datetime variable in sql server 2008 like:

```
declare @tmpStart DateTime = '2011/04/01' --(April 01, 2011)
```

What I am trying is to subtract one day from this date via:

```
declare @newDate DateTime = DateAdd(DAY,-1,@tmpStart)
```

This is returning 2011-03-30 instead 31. Where is my mistake? Why day 31 is skipped?

Comment: Strange... those exact statements work for me.  Perhaps there's an issue with localization settings/time zones?

Comment: No repro. Where are you?

Comment: Agreed, no reproduction --  that returns 2011-03-31 here also.

Comment: What happens if you use `declare @tmpStart DateTime = convert(varchar(10),'2011-04-01',120)` ??

Comment: What does `declare @newDate DateTime = DateDiff(DAY, 1 , @tmpStart)`, `SELECT @newDate` return for you?

Comment: Hey JiggsJedi, thanks it is working! What should be my problem in this regard? why the regular code doesnt work here?

Comment: I don't know, @Sturgus is on to something with locale settings though...  I've never encountered this before.  As a general rule though, I never use DD/MM or MM/DD for this exact reason, I use YYYY-MM-DD exclusively.

Comment: What is the exact result you get for the original query. Including time part?

Comment: 2011-03-30 00:00:00.000

Comment: What is the value of @tmpStart if you select it immediately after declaration?  Including time part?  Could SQL somehow be setting it as 3/31 and you are subtracting a day from that?

Comment: I wonder if this could be related to daylight savings time.  Certain areas in the Middle East did not experience midnight at the time -- the time immediately went forward one hour (http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2011.html).  I could speculate that with these locale settings, the midnight time was converted to a millisecond (or 3) earlier and that might explain the results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No. I checked for 2016-03-13 and 2016-11-06 on SQL 2012 and 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Very weird and shouldn't happen but you can probably try this and this might help you narrow down the problem. Try subtracting the minutes and you will figure out if you have to change any settings, if required, you can probably calculate differences in minutes.

```
declare @tmpStart DateTime = '2011/04/01'

declare @newDate DateTime = DateAdd(MINUTE,-1440,@tmpStart)
declare @newDate1 DateTime = DateAdd(MINUTE,-1400,@tmpStart)

select @newDate
-- 2011-03-31 00:00:00.000
select @newDate1
-- 2011-03-31 00:40:00.000
```

Comment: **-1400** vs **-1440** ;)